# Conditional Regular expression to check URL

Tags: java, regex

I need to check the URL to determine something.

The URL can be of two types :

```
  /anything/flows/anything/something.xhtml 
  /anything/solutions/dev/something.xhtml
```

**EDIT**

The above are the two url patterns in my application. I am getting the current URL from the request and trying it check it against a pattern and then match it. If it matches the pattern, then I need to set a few variables.

As of now, I have been using a pattern like this to check the second type of URL

```
public static final Pattern CHECK_PATTERN =  Pattern.compile("/([^)]+)/solutions/(dev|code)/([^)]+)");
```

And to check the first pattern, I used to split the URL and use `.contains` to check if the URL contains 'flows' and then do the necessary steps accordingly.

I was looking for a single regular expression that can be used to check both these type of URLs and hence reduce the if conditions. 
How can the conditional regular expressions help in achieving this?

Comment: You might start and tell us what you have tried, in which context you want to check that and what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this regex for for cases that you have mentioned.
/anything/((flows/[a-zA-Z]+)|(solutions/dev))/[a-zA-z]+.xhtml
It should work fine.